# Passing parameter for mvn test from pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a springboot project with tests
there are few parameters(for ex passwords, pins etc) i would like to pass for mvn tests, I know this can be done with -D option from the cli. Can these values be passed from pom.
Below didnt seem to work, i guess this is for execution and not for compilation

```
<properties>
    <someproperty> abcd </someproperty>
</properties>
```

Comment: You can try configuring surefire plugin http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Comment: Usually you should use the `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` instead of using system properties...

Comment: @khmarbaise thats not always helpful, for instance passwords. sorry i didnt mention it before. update the Q

Comment: Password should not even necessary in tests. They should be stored in vault etc. not in -D which are part of a pom file....

Comment: nope, they arent fed as property but rather via yml or property files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>@{argLine} -Dsomeproperty=someValue </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This did the trick.
Answering my question in case someone else needs this